# How to compare null values in the same table in sql

Tags: sql, null

For example, I have plenty of null variables in the table.

[image]

My target is to get all columns that are null in #apple but not null in #pear. In this example, it should be

[image]

I know how to do it in python and R but need help solving this in SQL. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
SELECT unique_code, apple, pear
FROM yourTable
WHERE apple IS NULL AND pear IS NOT NULL;
```

Note that to compare a column against `NULL` we must use the `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` operators.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE apple IS NULL AND pear IS NOT NULL;
```